# How can I grant certain classes to set my properties in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Two questions:

1. How can I allow only certain class to update a property? I tried using category but the NotFriendly class is still able to set the age property via Key-Value.
2. How come I get the "-[Person setAge:]: unrecognized selector sent" error when I tried to the age property during runtime?

Thanks,

Person.h

```
@interface Person

@property (readonly) NSString *age;

@end
```

Person.m

```
@implementation Person

@synthesize age;

@end
```

Person+Exclusive.h

```
@interface Person

@property (readwrite) NSString *age;

@end
```

Person+Exclusive.h

```
@implementation Person (Exclusive)

@end
```

Friendly.m

```
#import "Person+Exclusive.h"

@interface Friendly

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Person *aPerson = [[Person alloc] init];
    aPerson.age = @"12"; // -[Person setAge:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174013e90
}
```

NotFriendly.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@interface Friendly

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Person *aPerson = [[Person alloc] init];
    [aPerson setValue:@"1000000" forKey:@"age"]; // how can I stop this
}
```

Comment: This isn't C++, we trust programmers to do the right thing. Basically we rely on only putting public methods and properties in the header file, the rest goes in a class extension in the implementation file. Then we trust the developer to make the right calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably. Any method added to an Objective-C class is visible to everyone in the runtime; available methods are how key-value coding works.

If it's just KVC you want to block then you can override `setValue:forKey:` and decline to act if the names key is on your blacklist; otherwise call up to `super`. But classes will still be able to `performSelector:withObject:` or even drop down to the C runtime, the latter of which you can ultimately do nothing about.

If you are in a position where `Person` can be responsible for creating those objects that are permitted to talk to it then it can demand an instance as an argument to the setter and continue only if that instance is one you created. Keep a list in one of the weak collections of everything you instantiated.

In any detected failing case, by whatever means, you can manually raise an `NSException` to create the type of failure you desire.

If it's just for debugging builds and you don't mind a bunch of hassle, you can call `[NSThread callStackSymbols]` and parse the result to find out which type of class is calling. The text returned has no formally defined format though it's been fairly stable until now; it's explicitly not reliable for release builds. But it shouldn't be too much work to keep it working within debug builds as a diagnostic tool.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but it is an interesting question.

I wonder if you could create a method in person that takes two arguments, age and class. Then when you call it, you use [self class] to pass in the class. Something like this:

```
- (void)checkTheClassBeforeSettingAge:(NSString *)age withClass:(NSClass *)class {
   if (class isKindOfClass:[validClass class]) then {
     self.age = age;
   } else {
     // Error handling code
  }
}
```

Call it with:

```
checkTheClassBeforeSettingAge:@"12" withClass:[self class];
```

Comment: Problem with that is that the caller can lie and just pass in another class.